# Woocommerce notice makes custom js not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a simple flyout cart menu for a woocommerce shop. It works as expected, unless a woocommerce notice gets printed. Basically after user updates cart, adds product to the shopping bag, and other woocommerce actions that triggers the woocommerce notice to print.

[image: After adding a product to the cart, the notice appears above the content]

You can see the issue on the [dev site](http://lines.screenpartner.no/), try opening the cart in the top right, and try the same after a woocommerce notice gets printed.

The js for the cart is pretty simple and shouldn't be an issue:

```
/* This function allows the user to open and close the flyout mini cart */
$('.mini_cart_button, .close-cart').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#flyout-cart').toggleClass("open");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm using header fragments and calling the markup with a function:

```
<?php echo lines_header_cart_btn(); ?>
```

This is the function that creates the markup and also updates the cart button when a product is added:

```
// Function that creates the markup for the mini cart button
function lines_header_cart_btn() {
  $button_markup = '';
  $cart_link = '#';
  $number_of_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
  $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

  if ($number_of_products == 0) {
    $button_markup = '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="pink-btn mini_cart_button">';
    $button_markup .= $number_of_products . ' varer';
    $button_markup .= '</a>';
  } elseif ($number_of_products > 1) {
    $button_markup = '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="pink-btn mini_cart_button">';
    $button_markup .= $number_of_products . ' varer - kr ' . $cart_subtotal;
    $button_markup .= '</a>';
  } else {
    $button_markup = '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="pink-btn mini_cart_button">';
    $button_markup .= $number_of_products . ' vare - kr ' . $cart_subtotal;
    $button_markup .= '</a>';
  }
  return $button_markup;
}


// Ajaxifies lines_header_cart_btn()
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  ob_start();

  echo lines_header_cart_btn();

  $fragments['a.mini_cart_button'] = ob_get_clean();
  return $fragments;
}
```

Comment: I have added a product to the cart and I don't see any notice...

Comment: @ThemesCreator Are you sure? Check out the screenshot I added in my question to reference the look of the notice.